# Adding a list of unique values to an existing DataFrame column

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, set

I want to add a list of unique values to a DataFrame column. There is the code:

```
IDs = set(Remedy['Ticket ID'])
log['ID Incidencias'] = IDs
```

But I obtain the following error:

```
ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
```

Any idea about how could I add a list of unique values to an existing DataFrame column?

Thanks

Comment: When you try to assign a set of values to a dataframe's column, the number of values being assigned must be of same length as the dataframe

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you really need, but to add a list or set of values to each row of an existing dataframe column you can use:

```
log['ID Incidencias'] = [IDs] * len(log)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': list('abc')})

IDs = set((1,2,3,4))
df['col2'] = [IDs] * len(df)

print(df)
#  col1          col2
#0    a  {1, 2, 3, 4}
#1    b  {1, 2, 3, 4}
#2    c  {1, 2, 3, 4}
```